# using params from YAML header with a shiny runtime Rmd

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, shiny-reactivity

I would like to use `params` to pass settings for a shiny app. Consider the following document, which just prints a message when the checkbox is changed. I would like the message to be configuable using `params` in the yaml header.

However, it seems this fails as `params` seems to be only available when the document is rendered (notice that it correctly prints the message in the document itself). Is this correct? Is there any way of reading `params` at runtime? Is this documented anywhere?

Document is below:

````
---
title: "Test"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
params:
  message: "hi"
---

Can see this: `r params$message`

```{r eruptions, echo=FALSE}
shiny::checkboxInput("cb","Checkbox")
```

```{r, echo=FALSE}
observeEvent(input$cb, {
  # This works
  message("clicked")
  # This fails:
  # Error in message(params$message) : object 'params' not found
  try(message(params$message))
})
```
````

Comment: Weird. Maybe add `params <<- params` in a chunk at the beginning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works by setting `params` to a non-local variable:

````
---
title: "Test"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
params:
  message: "hi"
---

```{r}
params <<- params
```
......
````